# Too much requests on the same api

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4, dingo-api

We have a website and we’re using dingo api with laravel but there is a problem if the requests was too many on the same post api the server may be done what is the solution for that

Answer (score 0):

Not just for the dingo API:

1. **Reject the meaningless request.** 
   Add signature parameter into the API request based on business parameters and URL etc. to eliminate invalid requests from robots. You can also add timestamp parameters to prevent replay attacks. For your server side, When you receive the request, firstly should check whether the signature is correct. If it is not correct, you can reject it directly.
2. **Make your service scalable.** 
   If all requests are the expected legitimate request, try to deploy your services on more servers, let your service scale horizontally through load balancing (Referring to [ELB](https://aws.amazon.com/cn/elasticloadbalancing/)).
3. **Frequency control if non-scalable.** 
   If it is limited by server resources, it needs to be handled according to the actual situation. A common way is to add frequency control, that is to add some restrictions to the gateway or web server side. You need to know the maximum amount of traffic (QPS) that the available resource can accept，if the number of requests exceeds the maximum value in unit time， reject the exceeded requests to ensure that the servers do not fail and handle more within the capabilities.

Comment: Our server is limited we can’t make it scalable now so we can use number 3 solution thanks